# Reactor GroupedFlux - wait to complete

Tags: java, project-reactor

Having an async publisher like the one bellow, is there a way with Project Reactor to wait till the entire stream is finished processing?
Of course, without having to add a sleep for an unknown duration...

```java
    @Test
    public void groupByPublishOn() throws InterruptedException {
        UnicastProcessor<Integer> processor = UnicastProcessor.create();

        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
        Flux<Flux<Integer>> groupPublisher = processor.publish(1)
                                                      .autoConnect()
                                                      .groupBy(i -> i % 2)
                                                      .map(group -> group.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()));

        groupPublisher.log()
                      .subscribe(g -> g.log()
                                       .subscribe(results::add));

        List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 11, 12, 13);
        input.forEach(processor::onNext);
        processor.onComplete();

        Thread.sleep(500);

        Assert.assertTrue(results.size() == input.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace these lines:

```java
groupPublisher.log()
  .subscribe(g -> g.log().subscribe(results::add));
```

with this

```java
groupPublisher.log()
  .flatMap(g -> g.log().doOnNext(results::add))
  .blockLast();
```

`flatMap` is a better pattern than subscribe-within-subscribe and will take care of subscribing to the group for you.

`doOnNext` takes care of the consuming side-effect (adding values to the collection), freeing you up from the need to perform that in the subscription.

`blockLast()` replaces the subscription, and rather than letting you provide handlers for the events it blocks until the completion (and returns the last emitted item, but you would already have taken care of that within doOnNext).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't call `blockLast()` right away. I use the `UnicastProcessor` as a "hot source" to push events that I receive from an external system. So after I define the stream I want to start subscribing for events. I need to wait for completion only in tests. Is there another way to this without  `blockLast()`?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out that I can use the result from `flatMap()` to call `subscribe()` on it. And then from the tests call the `onComplete()` and `blockLast()`.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem to use **blockLast()** is that you will never release your pipeline if your operation are not able to finish.

What you need to do is get the **Disposable** and check if has finish the pipeline which means the boolean **isDisposed** it will return true.

Then it´s up to you to decide if you want to have a timeout, like the lazy count implementation :)

```java
@Test
public void checkIfItDisposable() throws InterruptedException {
  Disposable subscribe = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
      .map(number -> {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return number;
      }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newElastic("1"))
      .subscribe();
  while (!subscribe.isDisposed() && count < 100) {
    Thread.sleep(400);
    count++;
    System.out.println("Waiting......");
  }
  System.out.println("It disposable:" + subscribe.isDisposed());
}
```

And in case you want to use **blockLast**, at least add a timeout

```java
@Test
public void checkIfItDisposableBlocking() throws InterruptedException {
  Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
      .map(number -> {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return number;
      }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newElastic("1"))
      .blockLast(Duration.of(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
  System.out.println("It disposable");
}
```

You can see more Reactor examples here if you need more ides https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I wanted to avoid `Tread.sleep`. `blockLast` works fine.